# How to get the "out of office status" from the microsoft graph api?

Tags: rest, microsoft-graph-api

How can I retrieve the out of office status from the microsoft graph api? I don't see any REST method for this information.

Thanks for assistance in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `automaticRepliesSetting` in Graph:

```
<ComplexType Name="mailboxSettings">
    <Property Name="automaticRepliesSetting" Type="microsoft.graph.automaticRepliesSetting"/>
    <Property Name="archiveFolder" Unicode="false" Type="Edm.String"/>
    <Property Name="timeZone" Unicode="false" Type="Edm.String"/>
    <Property Name="language" Type="microsoft.graph.localeInfo"/>
</ComplexType>
```

Documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get-mailboxsettings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your solution but I get an ErrorAccessDenied.  Do you have an idea what has to be setup to work? I've got a token and I use this in my request.

Comment: I get the same error by trying on https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer with this get request: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/mailboxSettings

Comment: Okay I had to allow one more permission. Thanks for your help!

Comment: documentation link is broken

Comment: Try this link to the Documentation instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get-mailboxsettings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 0):

You can now get the out of office message through the Graph [Get presence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) **beta endpoint**.

```
GET /me/presence
GET /users/{id}/presence
GET /communications/presences
```

The **beta** endpoint response will have an [outOfOfficeSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/outofofficesettings?view=graph-rest-beta) property in it, that contains the out of office message